# Offset between table elements

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is a simple program that prints the references (so the memory addresses) of table elements.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string tab[5] = {"AA", "BBB", "CCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE"};
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"&tab["<<i<<"] = "<<&tab[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
&tab[0] = 0x7ffe34faf260                                                                                                                                                           
&tab[1] = 0x7ffe34faf268                                                                                                                                                           
&tab[2] = 0x7ffe34faf270                                                                                                                                                           
&tab[3] = 0x7ffe34faf278                                                                                                                                                           
&tab[4] = 0x7ffe34faf280
```

For me, an element of this table is a pointer to a string. So the size of each element is 8 Bytes.

**Assuming this is true, why the offset between tab[0] and tab[1] is 8 (Bytes), but the offset between tab[1] and tab[2] is just 2 Bytes.**

Comment: References are *not* memory addresses. A reference is an alias, it is completely different from a pointer in pretty much *every* respect. You're actually using pointers here, that's what the `&` operator does. Note that the `&` operator and the `&` type modifier are not the same thing.

Comment: Hint: What is `0x7ffe34faf270 - 0x7ffe34faf268`? The answer will surprise you!

Comment: See [Hexadecimal - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Answer (score 4):

Each element is a `std::string` object, not a pointer. The actual null-.terminated string data wrapped by the `std::string` objects could be stored on the heap, and don't affect the size of the object itself.

What you think is a difference of two bytes is actually a difference of *eight*, since the addresses are printed in [***hexadecimal***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). In hexadecimal `0x08 + 0x08 = 0x10`, since it's base-16.

Comment: I still wonder how `sizeof(std::string)` can be 8, but that's not part of the question I guess.

Comment: Maybe a [PImpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) implementation?